# How to allow only the owner to transfer ERC20 tokens during crowdsale?

Tags: solidity, transactions, tokens, ico, crowdsale

I recently came accross an ICO that used temp wallets. The tokens were sent to the investors manually which means that not everyone received their tokens at the same time. Until everyone received their tokens, they were locked for transfers. However the owner was able to transfer the tokens to the investors. For learning purposes I tried to reproduce this logic and I was wondering if my attempt could actually be used in terms of efficiency and security. The transferFrom function has the same logic.

Thanks for your feedback.

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(
        balances[msg.sender] >= _value
        && _value > 0
    );
    if(locked == true){
        if(msg.sender == owner){
            balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
            balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
            emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        }else{
            revert();
        }
    }else{
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid repeating logic:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);

    require(!locked || (msg.sender == owner));

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}
```

(I dropped the requirement that `_value >= 0` because ERC20 actually expects transfers of 0 to succeed.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a white list and a modifier

```
mapping (address => bool) allowTransfer;

modifier canTransfer(address user) {
    require(!locked || allowTransfer[user]);
    _;
}

function enableTransfer(address user, bool enable) onlyOwner {
    allowTransfer[user] = enable;
}
```

And you have to slightly modify the transfer function

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) 
        canTransfer(msg.sender) 
        public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}
```

Credits to the implementation of [ReleseableToken](https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/ReleasableToken.sol) in TokenMarket repos.